# Projectile test jump to failed test using gtest

Tags: projectile, c++, testing

I have projectile setup on a meson built cpp-project. I can compile and test via projectile just fine, i.e. projectile calls ninja and navigates the errors, warnings in the results. But the test results are just shown as a plain text, so no direct navigation through failed ones. Is there a way to decorate the ninja test or the gtest output, would I need to setup some regexps? Couldn't find anything in docs on this subject.